# Start when data to show in datetime chart (Highcharts)

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, json

I am working on an all year chart, but I have a little trouble.

The chart start from January, where there is not data to show until May. Client only want the chart to star when there is data to show, and I don`t find any related option like "startWhenData" or sth like that.

Any ideas?

Thank you so much!

Comment: How are you setting up the highchart? post your code

Answer (score 0):

Set your xAxis min far enough back so you can see January.

```
xAxis: {
            type: 'datetime',
            min: Date.UTC( 2012,  12, 1)
        },
```

then pass in an array of arrays to the series data in the form:

```
data: [
    [date1,dataPoint1],
    [date2,dataPoint2],  
    ...
]
```

[JSFiddle of this in action.](http://jsfiddle.net/BCZhN/)

Comment: I have resolved avoiding null data positions before the first real data position... and it works!